# NSRange : from Objective-C to Java

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, translation

I have to translate this based Objective-C code

```
  for (i = (int)[annots Size]-1; i>=0; --i) {
            PTField *field = [[PTField alloc] initWithField_dict: [annots GetAt: i]];
            NSString *nameField = [field GetName];
            NSRange range = [nameField rangeOfString:@"_FIXPDFBOX"];
            if ( range.location != NSNotFound ) {   
                NSRange sub = NSMakeRange( 0, range.location );                 
                [field Rename:[nameField substringWithRange:sub]];
            }
        }
```

Into Java. here is what i did :

```
for (i = annots.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                    Field field = new Field(annots.getAt((int) i));
                    String nameField = field.getName();

                    int range = nameField.indexOf("_FIXPDFBOX");
                    if (range != -1) {
                        int sub = range;
                        field.rename(nameField.substring(sub));
                    }
                }
```

(PTField is Field in Java).
But I think my problem is when translating NSRange into Java. Could you please help me to translate this ?

Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: what is the problem actually?

Comment: `i` has to be declared. `for (int i = ` (unless you declared it outside the for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
            for (i = annots.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
                Field field = new Field(annots.getAt((int) i));
                String nameField = field.getName();

                int range = nameField.indexOf("_FIXPDFBOX");
                int size = "_FIXPDFBOX".length();
                if (range != -1) {
                    int sub = range;
                    field.rename(nameField.substring(sub, sub+size));
                }
            }
```

Comment: "i" should be declared

for(int i=annots.size()-1; i>=0; --i)

Comment: Yes. if he hasn't declared it outside of the loop then it should be.